# off() in jQuery not removing the mouse listeners

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I use `.on()` to bind some mouse events to a html5 canvas. To unbind those events I use `.off()`. But still the functions are getting fired. I am using jQuery 1.9.2.

```
$('body').on('mousedown',$('#drawingCanvas'),function (e) { 
  handleMouseDown(e);
});
$('body').on('mousemove',$('#drawingCanvas'),function (e) {  
   handleMouseMove(e);
});
$('body').on('mouseup',$('#drawingCanvas'),function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$('body').on('mouseout',$('#drawingCanvas'),function (e) {      
    handleMouseOut(e);
    isMouseDown = false;
});

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY); 
    if (isMouseDown) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        context.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        context.stroke();
        lastX = mouseX;
        lastY = mouseY;
    }
}

$('body').off('mousedown',$('#drawingCanvas'));
$('body').off('mousemove',$('#drawingCanvas'));
$('body').off('mouseup',$('#drawingCanvas'));   
$('body').off('mouseout',$('#drawingCanvas'));
```

Comment: Why use a jquery object as the second argument of `on` when a selector would be sufficient?

Comment: @BasWildeboer Because it is also a selector.Is there any problem using it?

Comment: @BasWildeboer ya, because anyway in case second argument is not a string selector, it is just ignored

Comment: @DeeputheDon no, it is not. Here it is the same has just setting event on body, no delegation is used

Comment: @A.Wolff. Sorry i am new to jQuery can you show me how to correct it?

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you very much. I got it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('body').on('mousedown','#drawingCanvas',handleMouseDown);`

`$('body').off('mousedown',handleMouseDown);`